# Draw better identity arrows in tikz

Tags: tikz-arrows

I work on TexMaker, and I would like to insert an identity arrow shaped like a long equal in a tikz diagram, and to do so people on internet often suggest to use the edge style "double". The problem is that I don't find the output very appealing (It has lateral edges that make it look like a box):

```
\documentclass[tikz,10pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,arrows}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (m) [matrix of math nodes, row sep=3em,
column sep=2.5em, text height=1.5ex, text depth=0.25ex]
{ X & X \\ };
\path[-,font=\scriptsize]
(m-1-1) edge[double,thick,double distance=5pt] (m-1-2);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I also tried the "transform canvas" option to draw a pair of parallel arrows, but it's very messy and the distance between the two edges doesn't seem to be constant. Is there an easier way to get a nice output?

Comment: Those edges are a viewer artifact I think, I see them in Evince, but not TeXworks or Okular.

Comment: Is this for commutative diagrams?

Comment: Commutative, homotopy commutative, your pick. Let's say that it's for a generic diagram of arrows :)

Comment: Why not `double distance=2\fontdimen22\font`?

Comment: Ok, I can confirm that my problem was due to the fact that my version of tikz was obsolete. Sorry for the disturb and thanks for the help.

Comment: I signal that i can still see the side edges if I open the pdf file with Foxit Reader (although it doesn't happen anymore in the internal pdf viewerof TexMaker), so @TorbjørnT. was (at least partially) right.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the `equal` "arrow" from [`tikz-cd`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikz-cd).

1. Using directly `tikz-cd` (if you are planning to draw a commutative diagram):

   ```
   \documentclass[10pt]{article}
   \usepackage{tikz-cd}

   \begin{document}

   \begin{tikzcd}
    X \ar[r,equal] & X 
   \end{tikzcd}

   \end{document}
   ```

[image]

2. Using the `tikz-cd` features (in particular, `equal`) with your TikZ matrix:

   ```
   \documentclass[10pt]{article}
   \usepackage{tikz-cd}
   \usetikzlibrary{matrix,arrows}

   \begin{document}

   \begin{tikzpicture}[commutative diagrams/every diagram]
   \matrix (m) [matrix of math nodes, row sep=3em,
   column sep=2.5em, text height=1.5ex, text depth=0.25ex]
   { X & X \\ };
   \path[commutative diagrams/.cd, every arrow, every label,font=\scriptsize]
   (m-1-1) edge[commutative diagrams/equal] (m-1-2);
   \end{tikzpicture}

   \end{document}
   ```

[image]

The `minimal` class is so minimal that it's better not to use it except for test documents containing no much more than "Hello world!"

Comment: I'm sorry but if i try to compile this script it returns me this error:
"! Package tikz-cd Error: Arrow direction argument must contain only the characters l, r, u or d."
Did I do something wrong?

Comment: @LK512 You need an updated version of `tikz-cd`. Which version do you use?

Comment: @LK512 Try this (using the old syntax): `\documentclass[tikz,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}
 X \ar[equal]{r} & X 
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}`

Comment: No, still not working:
"! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/equal' and I am going to ignore it."
Plus I'm trying to figure out which version of tikz-cd I'm using but I don't know where to look (I'm working on Windows 7).

Comment: @LK512 Ah, that error message strongly suugests that your version is old. Run `\documentclass[tikz,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\listfiles
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}
 X & X 
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}` which shouldn't give any errors and check the .log file or the console for the section `*File List*; there you can find the version of `tikz.cd` in your system.

Comment: Yes, this time it worked: i'm running tikz-cd 2012/07/17 v0.2c (it seems pretty old indeed). Do you think that updating it could solve my problem?

Comment: @LK512 Really outdated. My system has  version `2014/10/30 v0.9e Commutative diagrams with tikz`. I suggest you update your packages (you will probably need to update `tikz-cd` and PGF/TikZ); the best thing to do would be to update your whole LaTeX System. Once you update your system, my code will work flawlessly and you'll have the latest versions of all packages (which, in the case of tikz-related packages) is always good.